# Why is ".dart" needed for import?

Tags: dart

When you import a package, you do:

```
import 'package:pkg_name/some_package.dart';
```

Why is `.dart` needed? Can you import files other than `.dart`?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a file ending in a non .dart suffix and import it. For example if you had the following in `example.nondartsuffix`:

```
String foo() => 'foo';
```

You could import it with `import 'example.nondartsuffix'` and it would work. However, that's not particularly useful, since it still must be valid Dart code.

The current import syntax is pretty verbose, and there is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10018) for improving it (removing the .dart suffix along with some other suggestions).